# Python os.pipe location in Windows systems

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, python-os

I am trying to create pipes in Windows 10, using Python 3.7. It seems the os module supplies this so I tried.

```
r, w = os.pipe()
```

returns two file descriptor (3 and 4) but the child process can't find these when entered like this.

**error:**

```
Error writing trailer of pipe:3: Bad file descriptor
```

I looked in the named pipes folder and couldn't find these descriptors there, I thought maybe I could find a location as a string to enter in the child process, such as:

`"\\.\\pipe\\3"` or `"\\.\\pipe\\4"`

But I couldn't. What is the complete address of the pipes created by `os.pipe()` in Windows ?

Comment: Have you made sure that `subprocess` is configured to make those file descriptors inheritable? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#fd-inheritance and the `close_fds` argument to `Popen` and children. (There's also `pass_fds`, but I'm not sure that it's supported on Windows).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I did not, however I moved on to using `win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe`. However I am curious about Unix/Windows compatibility. Should I continue with `os.pipe` ?

Comment: No idea -- my expertise is only on the UNIX side of the world, so anywhere I opine on the Windows end is strictly speculative.

Comment: ...that said, have you tested whether adjusting the parameters discussed above impacts whether your original attempts with `\\.\\pipe\\...` work?